# Taking Screenshot Ionic framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm building Ionic application that have geolocation (Google Api), but that's irelevant, in upper right corner is button which i want to make to take screenshot and automatically make popover with options to send that screenshot image via email, viber..., but i don't have an idea how to take that screenshot, I googled and googled without any luck, please help.

```
app.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaGeolocation, $ionicLoading, $ionicPlatform) {

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

        $ionicLoading.show({
            template: '<ion-spinner icon="bubbles"></ion-spinner><br/>Acquiring location!'
        });

        var posOptions = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 20000,
            maximumAge: 0
        };
        $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions).then(function (position) {
            var lat  = position.coords.latitude;
            var long = position.coords.longitude;

            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);

            var mapOptions = {
                center: myLatlng,
                zoom: 16,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };          

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);          

            $scope.map = map;   
            $ionicLoading.hide();   

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Lokacija'
        });


        }, function(err) {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            console.log(err);
        });
    });               
});
```

[image: Preview]

Answer (score 0):

Two options, as far as I can tell:

- Use a third-party Cordova plugin, such as https://github.com/gitawego/cordova-screenshot - this will most likely include the application's UI elements too, though, which might not be what you want.
- Perhaps a better idea would be to use the [Google Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/) - you can pass the current parameters from your dynamic map to it, and it'll return an image version.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started: [How to take a screen shot in ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34251687/5553633)

After you received the picture from the plugin, you can just use ionic's popover service to display it there.

Comment: actually i stucked again, dont know how to retrive picture from that service via controller MapCtrl and asign it to variable

Comment: Sorry for the long waiting time, was away over the weekend. If i see it correctly, the service should return it right to you, so you can, for example, create an <img> tag and as source attribute you can just take the "result" you get when calling the service. As you can see in the service, he's assining the file path to the promise and then returns the promise, so in then(result) is your file Path from the taken photo

Answer (score 0):

This below code should help
*The function will take screenshot and share popup
For More details you can visit [SocialSharing](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing) and [Screenshot](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/screenshot) **Ionic** offical page

```
import { SocialSharing } from '@ionic-native/social-sharing/ngx';
import { Screenshot } from '@ionic-native/screenshot/ngx';

constructor(
private socialSharing: SocialSharing,
private screenshot: Screenshot
) { }

 share(){
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.screenshot.URI(80)
        .then((res) => {
         //this.socialSharing.share('df',res.URI,null)
         this.socialSharing.share('',null,res.URI,null)
           .then(() => {},
             () => { 
               alert('SocialSharing failed');
             });
           },
          () => {
          alert('Screenshot failed');
          });
        });
  }
```